# How to remove XML tag nodes while preserving their inner child content from bash/shell

Tags: xml, bash, sed, grep, xml-parsing

I have a set of XML documents with some extraneous markup that I need to remove. This is one particular element which needs to be removed only when it has no attribute.

I need to remove the tags nodes but preserve the inner child nodes (*keeps the text*).

In Gitbash for Windows, I can easily find the required pattern using grep/sed with a regex. I can also easily remove both tags and also the text using sed. I don't know how to remove the tags but **leave** the text.

I need to be able to remove the two tags from instances like these:

```xml
<hi>some text</hi>
<hi>some different text</hi>
```

But keep instance of the tag when it has an attribute like:

```xml
<hi type="bold">some words</hi>
<hi type="italic">other words</hi>
```

For example:

```xml
<p>In my XML, <hi>this should have no markup</hi> and <hi>neither should this</hi> but <hi type="bold">this markup needs to be retained</hi></p>
```

The result when discarding the `<hi>` tag node without attribute but keeping its inner content would be:

```xml
<p>In my XML, this string should have no markup and neither should this but <hi type="bold">this markup needs to be retained</hi></p>
```

Can this be done using sed and regular expressions?

Comment: As you want to remove specific tag nodes depending on their attribute or absence of attribute, this is exactly the job for an XML processor/parser like `xsltproc` or `saxon`, with the help of an XSLT. Regexes, grep, sed... are not appropriate to manipulate the syntax complexity of markup languages like xml.

Comment: Use an XSLT template, (as suggested by @LéaGris), such as [this example](https://paste.ee/p/SgUdj) and then utilize a command-line tool such as [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) or [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to perform the transformation.